# husky pre-push exits with code 0 but the push never happens

Tags: git, husky, git-husky

I am exiting with code 0 in my `pre-push` hook, but the push never happens.
Any idea why my hooks ends successfully but the push does not happen?

here is my `husky.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    'post-checkout': 'post-checkout',
    'pre-commit': 'lint-staged',
    'commit-msg': 'commit-msg && commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS',
    'pre-push':
      'yarn && yarn lint && yarn build && yarn test && echo $? && exit 0'
  }
};
```

> [troubleshoot](https://github.com/typicode/husky#troubleshoot) ✅
>
> Git: `git version 2.24.2 (Apple Git-127)`
>
> OS: `macOS Catalina 10.15.3`
>
> Terminal: `VSCode 1.44.2`

Command:

```sh
HUSKY_DEBUG=1 yarn add husky --save-dev -W
```

Output:

```sh
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ husky@4.2.5
info All dependencies
└─ husky@4.2.5
$ patch-package
patch-package 6.2.0
Applying patches...
No patch files found
✨  Done in 27.15s.
```

Command:

```sh
HUSKY_DEBUG=1 git push
```

Output:

```sh
...
Test Suites: 8 passed, 8 total
Tests:       113 passed, 113 total
Snapshots:   7 passed, 7 total
Time:        16.087s
Ran all test suites in 8 projects.
0
husky:debug yarn run --silent husky-run exited with 0 exit code
```

Comment: Did you ever solved this?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did you verify if the changes are staged and committed?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think we just upgraded the version of husky to fix this, sorry I didn't answer it right when it was resolved.
Julio of course they were staged and committed, none of this would have even run if it wasn't.

Comment: For anyone coming across this – ran into this problem and the issue was that our tests were taking too long and Github was closing the connection before everything had finished.